Package name does not correspond to the file path after rebuild Intellij project to Maven
I have some Java project on the Intellij Idea IDE.
I learned foundations of Maven and decided rebuild my project on the Maven.
I added pom.xml file.
After that I have the mistake "Package name does not correspond to the path". class ApplicationRunner
My programm was succesfully compiled. It works. But source classes highlight this problem of the code.
I tried rename my package with recommendation of Intellij, but my tree of project breaks

Check your path settings in IntelliJ! Which path is mark as the source path in IDEA? And which build is successful? That one inside IDEA, or the standalone  one?

Remove main.java. from the package name. That will solve it if the file is in the right directory ($MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR/src/main/java/com/magicvet/component) If it isn't, that's where it needs to be moved

please check and consider Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Hello. Thank you for answers! I just fixed the error. I carefully checked the project tree and it turned out that I had two packages "main". I fixed the structure.

If main and/or, ahem, java appear near the root of the package tree, that's likely to cause confusion since directories with those names are already present
